# How to disable Masonry bounce?

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

When Masonry is rearranged it transitions and then elements bounce into place. Is there anyway to remove Masonry bounce effect when transition is complete? I have searched Google with no luck.

Comment: I don't use Masonry, but is the ["animating" section](http://desandro.github.io/masonry/docs/animating.html) of the documentation not what you're looking for?

Comment: @Colin I had a look at this section and tried everything no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

I manage to remove the bounce by setting the transitionDuration to 0 :

```
$('.grid').masonry({
    columnWidth: 200,
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    transitionDuration: 0
});
```